# Cross-Compiling for BeagleBone Black on Windows?

Tags: eclipse, arm, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

I have tried quite a few things on the internet but all seems to be not working when I cross compile on eclipse (with GNU MCU ARM and Sourcery Lite ), the binary on the BB-Black gives segmentation fault. Did someone try cross-compiling in recent time?

Comment: What system is running on your BBB? Bare metal? some RTOS? Linux? BSD? Which distribution?

Comment: It is running Linux - Debian release. But we figured out that the problem was somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

**Setting up Beagle Board Tool chain for windows:**

Online tutorial: In the tutorial it is mentioned that how to setup    the tool chain in eclipse, cross compile on windows and deploy on the    windows. 
   -    http://jkuhlm.bplaced.net/hellobone/

Pre-Requisite:

In order for beagle-bone to work with your laptop, you need to
   install the driver for the beagle bone.

https://beagleboard.org/getting-started
   -    Follow the link above and download the drivers at step 2. 
   -    Important: To install the driver, you need to switch off the driver signature safety feature of windows OS. The instructions to do so is
   mentioned at the link below: 
   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71YAIw7_-kg&feature=youtu.be

Install the following:
   1.   Java SDK : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html

2. Install Eclipse IDE for C/C++

   - Any version of Eclipse IDE for C/C++ is ok.. We would recommend to use “Neon” version of Eclipse IDE.
   - Link to the Neon Version: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/neon/3/eclipse-cpp-neon-3-win32-x86_64.zip
   - Unzip the package at a convenient location and launch via eclipse..exe
3. After opening your Eclipse:

   - Go to: Help > Eclipse Market Place > Search “GNU MCU Eclipse Plugin” and Install
4. Linaro Tool chain : http://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest-7/arm-linux-gnueabihf/

   - Download the toolchain from the link above named “gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz”
   - Extract it to a convenient location, recommended “C:/Linaro”
5. Install GNU Make: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm
6. Now please open the online tutorial mentioned in the beginning of this article and follow step-4 onwards.
7. Use your programmer instincts to import the project, edit make file, launch the remote system via eclipse, create a SSH connection
   to beagle bone black.

Answer (score 1):

Now, in 2020 it is much simpler. Download "Code Composer Studio IDE for Windows Host" from https://www.ti.com/. It is an Eclipse based IDE, for many TI targets. It includes the compiler too.

Answer (score 1):

I created a repository providing an example how to cross-compile for the beagle bone black on both Linux and Windows (MacOS should be possible as well) with CMake. Also includes Eclipse project files and instructions on how to perform remote debugging with the TCF agent:

https://github.com/spacefisch/beaglebone-crosscompiling